# Snowflake - Can't copy JSON split files in Staging area to tables

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working with Snowflake and some JSON files that I need to upload into a Staging area.
Since Snowflake doesn't allow files whose size is bigger than 1GB, I had to split them into smaller files using 7zip.

[I ended up with 4 files like the ones below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJg5S.jpg)

[Files were uploaded to the Staging area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zouyc.jpg) with a pattern as you can see in the attached image.

I'm trying to copy those files in the Staging area to another table by using following commands

```
copy into yelp_user from @staging/yelp_academic_dataset_user.json.gz  file_format
                                  =(format_name=yelp_user) on_error='skip_file';
```

Which gets me this error:

```
002019 (0A000): SQL compilation error:JSON file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array. Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column.
```

Then I tried creating a JSON table as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE json_table_user(json_data variant);

copy into JSON_TABLE_USER  file_format =(format_name = 'yelp_user') files=('yelp_academic_dataset_user.json.001.gz','yelp_academic_dataset_user.json.002.gz','yelp_academic_dataset_user.json.003.gz','yelp_academic_dataset_user.json.004.gz') on_error = 'skip_file';
```

And I get errors saying that

```
Remote file 'https://gcpuscentral1-ncxq405-stage.storage.googleapis.com/tables/2807681033/yelp_academic_dataset_user.json.004.gz' was not found. There are several potential causes. The file might not exist. The required credentials may be missing or invalid. If you are running a copy command, please make sure files are not deleted when they are being loaded or files are not being loaded into two different tables concurrently with auto purge option.
```

This is driving me crazy as following tutorials on Snowflake's website won't help me.

Does anyone knows how I can copy those split files into a table the way I need to?

Comment: Why do you think Snowflake can't load files > 1gb? In the last COPY statement you give, where is the required FROM clause?

Comment: Because I tried to do that on the web client and I get the error about the maximum size allowed. On the other Copy statement, I didn’t include it as by default Snowflake will place last location I was working on which was the staging schema and where I have those files.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to use the WebUI to load large files. If your files are on a local PC then you need to use Snowsql to run a put command to load them into an internal stage; if your files are on AWS/Azure/GCP then you use an external stage. I suggest you always use a FROM clause rather than making assumptions about where Snowflake will look for the files

Comment: You can also split files using https://github.com/Mitch-Wheat/FileSplitter

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68718176/132438 to split files easily into smaller ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong in your process, but I found a similar file to repeat it.

In this case, instead of uploading to a Snowflake internal stage, I told Snowflake to read it from a GCS bucket. To do so, first I created an integration:

```sql
use role accountadmin;

CREATE STORAGE INTEGRATION fh_gcp
  TYPE = EXTERNAL_STAGE
  STORAGE_PROVIDER = GCS
  ENABLED = TRUE
  STORAGE_ALLOWED_LOCATIONS = ('gcs://fhoffa-snow/')  
;
describe integration fh_gcp; 
-- give access to the snowflake gcp account to the bucket in gcp
grant usage on integration fh_gcp to role sysadmin;
--

use role sysadmin;

create stage fh_gcp_stage
url = 'gcs://fhoffa-snow/'
storage_integration = fh_gcp;

list @fh_gcp_stage; -- check files exist
```

Then I slightly modified your SQL to read from this stage. Note that I didn't need to split the file, Snowflake is happy to read files larger than 1gb:

```sql
create temp table json_table_user(json_data variant);

copy into JSON_TABLE_USER
from @fh_gcp_stage
file_format = (type=json)
files=('202104/yelp_academic_dataset_user.json.gz') on_error = 'skip_file'
;
```

And then you can start having fun with queries and semi-structured data:

```sql
select median(json_data:average_stars) stars
    , median(json_data:review_count) reviews
    , median(json_data:funny) funny
    , median(json_data:useful) useful
    , count(*) c
from json_table_user ;
```

[image]

A quick fix to what you tried above could be reading the existing file into the table you created:

```sql
copy into json_table_user from @staging/yelp_academic_dataset_user.json.gz  file_format
                                  =(format_name=yelp_user) on_error='skip_file';
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe, that's a really good approach even thought I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Also about querying the data in the json tables, how do I retrieve value in "garage" within tje BusinessParking column.

{
  "address": "921 Pearl St",
  "attributes": {
    "Alcohol": "'beer_and_wine'",
    "Ambience": "{'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romantic': False, 'divey': False, 'intimate': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'classy': False, 'casual': True}",
    "BusinessParking": "{'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}"
}

I have tried: json_data:attributes.BusinessParking.garage but all I get are null values.

Comment: Happy to answer that one in a new question (for space and formatting)

Comment: Sorry but it's difficult to format code within a comment and that's how it went.

In case you can take a look into my other question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67305862/snowflake-get-value-of-key-in-an-object-within-another-object, I will very much appreaciate it.