# Snowflake - Get value of key in an object within another object

Tags: json, object, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image]I'm working with Snowflake and loading json files from a Staging environment to an ODS environment.

The structure of the json data looks like this:

```
{"address": "921 Pearl St",  
 "attributes": {
    "Alcohol": "'beer_and_wine'",
    "Ambience": "{'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romantic': False, 'divey': False, 'intimate': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'classy': False, 'casual': True}",
    "BikeParking": "True",
    "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin": "False",
    "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": "True",
    "BusinessParking": "{'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}"
}
```

Now I'm trying to query my data in Snowflake like this:

```
SELECT json_data:attributes.BusinessParking.garage
FROM my_json_table;
```

but all I get are null values.
Any idea how do I get to the bottom levels in the "BusinessParking" field?

thanks!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of research I'm able to query the fields the way I needed to.
I found out that  I need to use the "try_parse_json" functions with those fields as they are defined as strings not actual json objects.

After using the function I can parse specific fields just like this:

```
SELECT
 TRY_PARSE_JSON(
  jsondata: attributes.BusinessParking
 ): garage AS garage
FROM
 "RESTAURANT"."STAGING"."JSON_TABLE_BUSINESS"
```

Snowflake's doc isn't that great but somehow it explains what you can do: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_parse_json.html

This is another way you could transform string values to columns in case you need it: https://sqlkover.com/cool-stuff-in-snowflake-part-3-split-and-flatten/

Thanks for all the comments @simeon-pilgrim!

Answer (score 1):

Trying to parse the JSON in online tool I got:

```
Error: Parse error on line 9:
..., 'valet': False}"}
----------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', got 'EOF'
```

You could check if it is correct by running [TRY_PARSE_JSON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_parse_json.html):

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE_JSON(json_data) from my_json_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your object is missing a closing `}`

So if I rewrite you "JSON" to be valid then the select form you use works:

```
select parse_json('{
    "address": "921 Pearl St",  
    "attributes": {
        "Alcohol": "beer_and_wine",
        "Ambience": {
            "touristy": False, 
            "hipster": False, 
            "romantic": False, 
            "divey": False, 
            "intimate": False, 
            "trendy": False,
            "upscale": False, 
            "classy": False, 
            "casual": True
        },
        "BikeParking": True,
        "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin": "False",
        "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": "True",
        "BusinessParking": {
            "garage": False, 
            "street": True, 
            "validated": False, 
            "lot": False, 
            "valet": False
        }
    }
 }') as json_data,
json_data:attributes.BusinessParking.garage,
json_data:attributes:BusinessParking:garage
;
```

but as that implies your JSON is not valid.

looking at your `Ambience` it a stringfied JSON sub-object, not an object, thus the embedded `'` inside it. So escaping your '`' in the sub strings, to it parses correctly we will need to PARSE_JSON the sub-objects, thus:

```
select parse_json('{"address": "921 Pearl St",  
 "attributes": {
    "Alcohol": "\'beer_and_wine\'",
    "Ambience": "{\'touristy\': False, \'hipster\': False, \'romantic\': False, \'divey\': False, \'intimate\': False, \'trendy\': False, \'upscale\': False, \'classy\': False, \'casual\': True}",
    "BikeParking": "True",
    "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin": "False",
    "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": "True",
    "BusinessParking": "{\'garage\': False, \'street\': True, \'validated\': False, \'lot\': False, \'valet\': False}"
}}') as json_data,
PARSE_JSON(json_data:attributes.BusinessParking):garage
```

gives the answer `false` that you are looking for.

EDIT

to add more details, you object has json objects nestsed which are [Stringify'ed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

to put replicate that the above (and below) SQL uses escape tokens `\` to allow single quotes into the data. But after that we can select `json_data:attributes.BusinessParking` and see it presented like you have it shown in your example, which mean if we then PARSE_JSON on that, we get a valid JSON object again, which we can then access via `:garage`

```
select parse_json('{"address": "921 Pearl St",  
 "attributes": {
    "Alcohol": "\'beer_and_wine\'",
    "Ambience": "{\'touristy\': False, \'hipster\': False, \'romantic\': False, \'divey\': False, \'intimate\': False, \'trendy\': False, \'upscale\': False, \'classy\': False, \'casual\': True}",
    "BikeParking": "True",
    "BusinessAcceptsBitcoin": "False",
    "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": "True",
    "BusinessParking": "{\'garage\': False, \'street\': True, \'validated\': False, \'lot\': False, \'valet\': False}"
}}') as json_data,
json_data:attributes.BusinessParking as it_looks_the_same,
PARSE_JSON(it_looks_the_same) as valid_json,
valid_json:garage
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: I'm using this query:
`select
    json_data:attributes:BusinessParking
from "RESTAURANT"."STAGING"."JSON_TABLE_BUSINESS";`

then the object looks like this:
`"{'garage': False, 'street': True, 'validated': False, 'lot': False, 'valet': False}"`

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is a `string` not `JSON`, thus you cannot "access" it like JSON, you need to PARSE_JSON it, if you want it to be treated like JSON to allow you to access it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. What else do I need to do?

Using the parse_json function like this :
`select
    parse_json(json_data:attributes:BusinessParking) as garage
from "RESTAURANT"."STAGING"."JSON_TABLE_BUSINESS";` gets me this error
`Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "None", pos 16`

Comment: I feel that sort of proves my point, you don't have JSON, you have `something like JSON`, if it doesn't parse as JSON, it's not JSON. Thus you cannot access it as JSON structured data. This is a common data processing problem, you will need to find what the data is and how to clean it. Which is my main point. if you swap to `select json_data:attributes:BusinessParking as input,   try_parse_json(json_data:attributes:BusinessParking) as garage from "RESTAURANT"."STAGING"."JSON_TABLE_BUSINESS" where garage is null;` you will find the data you have that does not parse.

Comment: I tried to use something like `select parse_json(json_data):attributes.BusinessParking[0] as garage,
parse_json(json_data):attributes.BusinessParking[1], 
parse_json(json_data):attributes.BusinessParking[2] ,
parse_json(json_data):attributes.BusinessParking[3], 
parse_json(json_data):attributes.BusinessParking[4] ,
(json_data):attributes.BusinessParking[4] 
from "RESTAURANT"."STAGING"."JSON_TABLE_BUSINESS"` but that retrieves pure null values.

Comment: As per my understanding this is a json object inside the main variant field I created in Snowflake `"BusinessParking": {
            "garage": False, 
            "street": True, 
            "validated": False, 
            "lot": False, 
            "valet": False
        }` so I don't know if converting each one of those subfields can be converted into columns. Is that even possible?

Comment: @ilikawa I have added another edit, to try show how to access it.

Comment: to store the data the way you put it in your example, do I need to reload the data in the Staging area and then add the ESCAPE parameter in the COPY INTO statement?

Comment: No, I was just doing that so it would be the same as your data, because I am injecting the data via the WebUI the quotes have different meaning, so that has to be worked around.

Comment: I appreaciate all your help @simeon-pilgrim but I'm lost now.
Do I need to change something in the process I used to load the data from the json files to the Staging area or do I need to use somehow the parse_json function to access those specific fields? 

Any link to articles to get a better understanding will be very much appreaciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231769/discussion-between-simeon-pilgrim-and-ilikawa).